# Multiple Csv to json with no repetitive childrens

Tags: python, json, csv, d3.js

I have a csv columns as follows, now I am trying to convert it to name/Children/Size format as required in D3 in JSON. There are repetetive Childrens Occuring For example 
In name ="type" there is children ="young", size = 400000

```
L1       L2     L3         L4        L5      L6          Size
Type    cars    young      young     young   young      40000
Type    cars    student    US        US      US         10000
Type    cars    student    UK        UK      UK         20000
Type    cars    Graduates  Young    India    Delhi      20000
Type    cars    Graduates  Old      UK       London     30000
Type    Bike    Undergrads CB       CB       UNC        6000
prime   prime   prime      prime    prime   prime       600
```

My output I am getting is :

```
{
    "name": "Segments",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Type",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "cars",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "young",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "young",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "young",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "young",
                                                    "size": "40000"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "student",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "US",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "US",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "US",
                                                    "size": "10000"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "UK",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "UK",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "UK",
                                                    "size": "20000"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "prime",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "prime",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "prime",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "prime",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "prime",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "prime",
                                                    "size": "600"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

expecting output is:

```
{
    "name": "Segments",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Type",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "cars",
                    "children": [
                        {
                        "name": "young",
                        "size": "40000"
                        }
                                ]


                        },
                        {
                            "name": "student",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                 "name": "US",
                                 "size": "10000"
                                }

                                {
                                "name": "UK",
                                "size": "20000"
                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },

        {
        "name": "prime",
        "size": "600"
        }
        ]
        }
```

I am using Following code:

```
import json
import csv

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, size=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        self.size = size

    def child(self, cname, size=None):
        child_found = [c for c in self.children if c.name == cname]
        if not child_found:
            _child = Node(cname, size)
            self.children.append(_child)
        else:
            _child = child_found[0]
        return _child

    def as_dict(self):
        res = {'name': self.name}
        if self.size is None:
            res['children'] = [c.as_dict() for c in self.children]
        else:
            res['size'] = self.size
        return res


root = Node('Segments')

with open('C:\\Users\\G01172472\\Desktop\\Book3.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    p = list(reader)
    for row in range(1, len(p)):
        grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4, grp5, grp6, size = p[row]
        root.child(grp1).child(grp2).child(grp3).child(grp4).child(grp5).child(grp6, size)

print(json.dumps(root.as_dict(), indent=4))
```

Comment: How about just removing those extra columns ? That way your code works as expected.

Comment: @BcK I can not remove those extra columns because in some other row it may have unique values for all columns . i have edited the csv you can check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to first to is to remove duplicates from each row and create the children accordingly.

Here's what I changed:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\G01172472\\Desktop\\Book3.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    p = list(reader)
    for row in range(1, len(p)):
        temp = []  
        for x in p[row]:
            if x not in temp:
                temp.append(x) 
                #Create a temporary list of the row but keep only unique elements

        ## Additional code according to your dictionary structure
        #if row != 1:
        #    if 'cars' in temp:
        #       temp.remove('cars')
        #   elif 'Bike' in temp:
        #       temp.remove('Bike')


        # Create a string to which will look similar to root.child(grp1)...
        evalStr = 'root'
        for i in range(len(temp)):
            if i == len(temp)-2:
                evalStr += '.child("' + temp[i] + '","' + temp[-1] + '")'
            else:
                evalStr += '.child("' + temp[i] + '")'

        # eval(string) will evaluate the string as python code
        eval(evalStr)

print(json.dumps(root.as_dict(),indent=2))
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I Tried this approach but problem here is if there are some childrens inside children which are unique those are captured in grp1 itself

Comment: @CyleySimon Okay I sort of understood what you're trying to do. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: How Do i print the sresult over here in json format

Comment: @CyleySimon print(json.dumps(root.as_dict(), indent=4))

Comment: I tried this but it just prints {
    "name": "Segments",
    "children": []
}

Comment: @CyleySimon I hope your print statement is outside the json read function. Look at the updated code above

Comment: @CyleySimon Use result = json.dumps(root.as_dict()) and then just print result.
Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to remove the dups from your row. This can be done as follows,

```
p[row] = ('Type', 'cars', 'young', 'young', 'young', 'young', 'Size')
pp = set()

new_p_row = [el for el in p[row] if not (el in pp or pp.add(el))]
# ['Type', 'cars', 'young', 'Size']
```

Then add childrens to your root until the last two,

```
for r in new_p_row[:-2]:
    root.child(r)
```

Add the last child to your root with the size of it,

```
root.child(new_p_row[-2], new_p_row[-1])
```

Comment: with open('C:\\Users\\G01172472\\Desktop\\Book3.csv', 'r') as p:
    reader = csv.reader(p)
    p= list(reader)
    pp = set()
    new_p_row = [el for el in p if not (el in pp or pp.add(el))]
    for r in new_p_row[:-2]:
        root.child(r)
        root.child(new_p_row[-2], new_p_row[-1]  i have used this

Comment: @CyleySimon Careful, you should write `el for el in p[row]`, not `el for el in p`. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: but how do i get my csv data in p[row]

Comment: @CyleySimon You already have the line `for row in range(): p[row]` in your code, don't you ?